# Upload images to WinCC Unified from database in RunTime

Tags: javascript, plc, wincc

Hello I have a question about uploading images to WinCC Unified V17 from my external db. The database contains the file path of the images. According to the following product, a specific image need to be chosen from the database and will be shown on the screen.

How can I dynamically call a file path from the database and show it as an image on my screen while the WinCC is running ?

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: I guess you are really talking about _WinCC_ and *not* _WinCC OA_, right?

Comment: yes indeed Markus, my question was about WinCC

Comment: Since you apperently dubbelposted on sios (https://support.industry.siemens.com/forum/ww/en/posts/upload-images-to-wincc-from-database-in-runtime/276051/?page=0&pageSize=10)
Put the images in the subfolder "WinccUnified\WebRH\public" so that access via htpps is ok working?